# Embed Contact Card of Site Owner onto his Teamsite

Tags: 2013, web-part, team-sites, connection, contacts

as said in title i want to embed a small window (Webpart) onto a teamsite, showing the contact Card of the sites owner (like: width - 400 pixel).

The window should be linked dynamicly to the site contact (and/or his e-mail adress) and be placed on the lower edge of the site.

Any ideas how i could make this work?